# PuTTY + Ubuntu 12.10: why do I have no colors unless I use screen?

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, gnu-screen, ubuntu-12.10

I am accessing a new Ubuntu 12.10 installation via PuTTY. I am attempting to get my shell to display in color. Color works fine in interactive applications like `vim`, but I want to get color in e.g. my $PS1 prompt, `git`, `ls`, etc.

When I use a `screen` session, the color magically works. Without `screen` there is no color.

**Without screen:**

```
$ set |grep -i term
TERM=xterm
```

**With screen:**

```
$ set |grep -i term
TERM=screen
TERMCAP=$'SC|screen|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal:\\\n\t:DO=\\E[%dB:LE=\\E[%dD:RI=\\E[%dC:UP=\\E[%dA:bs:bt=\\E[Z:\\\n\t:cd=\\E[J:ce=\\E[K:cl=\\E[H\\E[J:cm=\\E[%i%d;%dH:ct=\\E[3g:\\\n\t:do=^J:nd=\\E[C:pt:rc=\\E8:rs=\\Ec:sc=\\E7:st=\\EH:up=\\EM:\\\n\t:le=^H:bl=^G:cr=^M:it#8:ho=\\E[H:nw=\\EE:ta=^I:is=\\E)0:\\\n\t:li#62:co#115:am:xn:xv:LP:sr=\\EM:al=\\E[L:AL=\\E[%dL:\\\n\t:cs=\\E[%i%d;%dr:dl=\\E[M:DL=\\E[%dM:dc=\\E[P:DC=\\E[%dP:\\\n\t:im=\\E[4h:ei=\\E[4l:mi:IC=\\E[%d@:ks=\\E[?1h\\E=:\\\n\t:ke=\\E[?1l\\E>:vi=\\E[?25l:ve=\\E[34h\\E[?25h:vs=\\E[34l:\\\n\t:ti=\\E[?1049h:te=\\E[?1049l:us=\\E[4m:ue=\\E[24m:so=\\E[3m:\\\n\t:se=\\E[23m:mb=\\E[5m:md=\\E[1m:mr=\\E[7m:me=\\E[m:ms:\\\n\t:Co#8:pa#64:AF=\\E[3%dm:AB=\\E[4%dm:op=\\E[39;49m:AX:\\\n\t:vb=\\Eg:G0:as=\\E(0:ae=\\E(B:\\\n\t:ac=\\140\\140aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~..--++,,hhII00:\\\n\t:po=\\E[5i:pf=\\E[4i:k0=\\E[10~:k1=\\EOP:k2=\\EOQ:k3=\\EOR:\\\n\t:k4=\\EOS:k5=\\E[15~:k6=\\E[17~:k7=\\E[18~:k8=\\E[19~:\\\n\t:k9=\\E[20~:k;=\\E[21~:F1=\\E[23~:F2=\\E[24~:F3=\\E[1;2P:\\\n\t:F4=\\E[1;2Q:F5=\\E[1;2R:F6=\\E[1;2S:F7=\\E[15;2~:\\\n\t:F8=\\E[17;2~:F9=\\E[18;2~:FA=\\E[19;2~:kb=\177:K2=\\EOE:\\\n\t:kB=\\E[Z:kF=\\E[1;2B:kR=\\E[1;2A:*4=\\E[3;2~:*7=\\E[1;2F:\\\n\t:#2=\\E[1;2H:#3=\\E[2;2~:#4=\\E[1;2D:%c=\\E[6;2~:%e=\\E[5;2~:\\\n\t:%i=\\E[1;2C:kh=\\E[1~:@1=\\E[1~:kH=\\E[4~:@7=\\E[4~:\\\n\t:kN=\\E[6~:kP=\\E[5~:kI=\\E[2~:kD=\\E[3~:ku=\\EOA:kd=\\EOB:\\\n\t:kr=\\EOC:kl=\\EOD:km:'
```

What is the `TERMCAP` environment variable, and how does it get set by `screen`? How can I get that to be set outside of `screen` (short of just copy-pasting it into my `.bashrc`)?

Comment: Do you get color if you use `ls --color=tty` instead of `ls`?

Comment: @terdon: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that `~/.bashrc` is not sourced when logging in directly via PuTTY, but it is when using a `screen` session. Apparently, logging in via PuTTY is considered a "[remote non login non interactive shell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles)".

As @terdon pointed out, `ls`, `grep` et al are colorless by default, but my `.bashrc` has it aliased to use colors.

My fix was to source .bashrc in my .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Any idea how you get PuTTY to act like a terminal client on Linux distributions so that it happens by default? I don't want to have to reconfigure my bash profile or force-colors on all Linux boxes I connect to

Comment: Actually this blog post summarises how you should configure PuTTY instead... using the terminal string of `putty-256color` would be a good start. The default of `xterm` is highly compatible, but pretty naff. http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/putty-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

`ls` etc do not use color by default, if you want to have the colored you need to set the specific option. You can do this globally by setting aliases in your `$HOME/.bashrc` file (on the remote server):

1. Set `$PS1` (this one is from my .bashrc., you can change it as desired):

   ```
   PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;33m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \\$\[\033[00m\] '
   ```

   This looks like so:
   [image]
2. Set aliases for (in this example `ls` and `grep` you need to find the appropriate option for `git` and any other programs you want to always have colored):

   ```
   alias grep='grep --color' 
   alias ls='ls --color=tty'
   ```

Comment: Hmm, it seems I have all of those defined as aliases when I use `screen`. My $PS1 is also different. I didn't realize screen did all of that.

Comment: I guess screen exports these variables by default. Does it work OK now @jbinto?